# Cannot read property Redux object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I think I have a really basic question. So on my index page, I have an input field that I take the number. According to this number I display my component which is on the next page. And I am storing them with Redux. So for example, if the user enters 3, on the next page I display the component 3 times. Everything is quite okay, I am getting the list successfully, which is showing the number of displays. But at the first time, I am getting `Cannot read property 'order_number_of_display' of undefined` which means if the page is rendered again, everything is working okay.

Anyway here how I get the number of display:

```
const newOrderList = useSelector((state) => state.newOrderList);
  const { newOrder } = newOrderList;
  const numberOfDisplay = newOrder.order_number_of_display;
```

And for the first time, it is undefined on my console but in Redux store, it is actually fulfilled. Could you give me a hint on how I can fix it?

Also, this is how I am displaying:

```
{
        Array.from({ length: numberOfDisplay }, (v, i) => ( 
<Component/>
)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `newOrderList` might not be an object ( may be null ) or it might be just an empty object. So there are 2 ways to fix this

1. Guard your `newOrderList` by setting default values

```
    const newOrderList = useSelector((state) => state.newOrderList);
    const { newOrder = {} } = newOrderList || {};
    const numberOfDisplay = newOrder?.order_number_of_display || 0
```

2. Set the initial value in the store for the state `newOrderList` in your reducer

Comment: My newOrderList is not null because I see it on the redux store. So, if I give the initial value wouldnt it show the initial value until the page renders again for some reason?

Comment: Okay . If its not null then can you tell what is its value in the store initially ? .  By initially i mean when your App is rendered for first time . If you have redux dev tools you can inspect there . if not i highly recommend you to install it . Other way is you can console the `newOrderList` below your `useSelector` in your component to check what it is .

Comment: Yes, I am using it and when I say newOrderList is not null, I saw it from there :) anyway, it shows exactly the same value on an input field.

Comment: what is the shape of  `newOrderList` is it a string or object . If it is an object what are the properties it has ? . you can edit your question with what you see in the dev tools for `newOrderList`

Comment: Actually, after i put the const { newOrder = {} }, it is solved but I coudlnt understand why I needed to set newOrder to am empty object

Comment: okay so let me ask you for the third time :-) what do you see in the dev tools for `newOrderList` can you add that in your question . I can explain better if i can see what it is .

Comment: Just edited my question, order_number_of_cars actually display in our case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233319/discussion-between-shyam-and-the-man-in-the-pink-suit).